PhotosPicker messes up detent
I have a view with an overlaying half sheet (for lack of better terms), which covers the bottom half of the screen. It's implemented like this:
.sheet(isPresented: $showSender, content: {
  SenderView()
    .presentationDetents([.medium])
}

If I set showSender to true upon launching, it looks just fine. However, I want the sheet to pop up upon selecting a photo. I'm using a PhotosPicker and setting showSender to true when the photo selected changes:
PhotosPicker("Send Pictures", selection: $photoPicked, matching: .images)
  .onChange(of: photoPicked) { value in
    self.showSender = true
}

However, bizarrely, in this case the sheet covers the whole screen. Any ideas what's going on? Here's a minimal repro. Thanks.
import SwiftUI
import PhotosUI

struct SenderView: View {
  var body: some View {
    Text("Sender View")
  }
}

struct ContentView: View {
  @State var showSender = false
  @State var photoPicked: PhotosPickerItem? = nil

  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      PhotosPicker("Send Pictures", selection: $photoPicked, matching: .images)
        .onChange(of: photoPicked) { value in
          self.showSender = true
        }
    }
    .padding()
    .sheet(isPresented: $showSender, content: {
      SenderView()
        .presentationDetents([.medium])
    })
  }
}

#Preview {
  ContentView()
}



I think this is caused by presenting the sheet when the photo picker is being dismissed, and breaking everything. This is probably not intended and might be fixed in a future iOS version. On macOS, this works as expected.
An alternative is to present the sheet first, then immediately the photo picker. If the user didn't select any photos, dismiss the sheet.
struct SenderView: View {
    @Binding var photoPicked: PhotosPickerItem?
    @State var showPhotoPicker = true
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    var body: some View {
        Text("Sender View")
            .photosPicker(isPresented: $showPhotoPicker, selection: $photoPicked, matching: .images)
            .onChange(of: showPhotoPicker) { oldValue, newValue in
                if !newValue && photoPicked == nil {
                    dismiss()
                }
            }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showSender = false
    @State var photoPicked: PhotosPickerItem? = nil
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Send Pictures") {
                showSender = true
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .sheet(isPresented: $showSender, content: {
            SenderView(photoPicked: $photoPicked)
                .presentationDetents([.medium])
        })
    }
}

